# Ending up with different dependency version in dotnet core

Tags: .net, .net-core

I'm working on a project that targets `netstandard1.6` and `net451`.
Unfortunatly I'm getting these warnings while building my library:

```
C:\Path\project.json(22,35): warning NU1007: Dependency specified was Microsoft.CSharp >= 4.0.1 but ended up with Microsoft.CSharp 4.0.0.0.
C:\Path\project.json(17,38): warning NU1007: Dependency specified was System.Collections >= 4.0.11 but ended up with System.Collections 4.0.0.0.
C:\Path\project.json(18,30): warning NU1007: Dependency specified was System.Linq >= 4.1.0 but ended up with System.Linq 4.0.0.0.
C:\Path\project.json(19,33): warning NU1007: Dependency specified was System.Runtime >= 4.1.0 but ended up with System.Runtime 4.0.10.0.
C:\Path\project.json(20,49): warning NU1007: Dependency specified was System.Runtime.InteropServices >= 4.1.0 but ended up with System.Runtime.InteropServices 4.0.10.0.
C:\Path\project.json(21,36): warning NU1007: Dependency specified was System.Threading >= 4.0.11 but ended up with System.Threading 4.0.0.0.
```

This is my `project.json`:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "description": "MyLibrary",

    "frameworks": {
        "net451": {
        },
        "netstandard1.6": {
        }
    },

    "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
        "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1",
        "MyOtherProject.Common": "1.0.0-*",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11",
        "System.Linq": "4.1.0",
        "System.Runtime": "4.1.0",
        "System.Runtime.InteropServices": "4.1.0",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11",
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1"
    }
}
```

The library builds with no error targeting `netstandard1.6` and `net451`, however I'm getting those warnings while building for `net451`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did You solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue.
My fix, that removed warnings was

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "MyLibrary",

  "frameworks": {
    "net451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.Collections": "4.0.0",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.0",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.10",
        "System.Runtime.InteropServices": "4.0.10",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.0",
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.0"
      }
    },
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11",
        "System.Linq": "4.1.0",
        "System.Runtime": "4.1.0",
        "System.Runtime.InteropServices": "4.1.0",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11",
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1"
      }
    }
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1"
  }
}
```

But I think there might be some better solution.